# Need a help figuring out some nested iteration things in Java

Tags: java, nested, iteration

I'm pretty new to programming and just started not to long ago doing some CS, currently my assignment is to is to write a program that prints each letter of the alphabet and the number of times that letter occurs in the phrase. It needs to include:

-Loop to iterate through the alphabet (the outer loop)
-Loop to iterate through all the letters of a phrase (the inner loop)
-Counter variable to count the number of times a letter is in the phrase
-Print statement to display the frequencies

I'm a little behind on this and having a hard time finding time to put into doing this assignment and just need some guidance on how to complete this simply, without complex things like Arrays and stuff.

As I said I haven't had much time to work on this, but here is the general layout/my plan of what I think it should look like:

```
public class LetterFrequencies
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int counter = 0;
        String letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"; 
        String phrase = "This is a phrase";

        System.out.println("The following shows the letter frequencies for the phrase");

    //for (int i = _; i < _; i++) ??
    {
      //Print out statement like :System.out.println(letters.substing());
    }
      //possible while loop or for loop? 
    }
}
```

Feel free to correct me and anyway necessary since I need all the knowledge I can get to improve in the near future, thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry but what do you mean by letter frequencies, for example, what would be the output for the phrase "This is a phrase".

Comment: The output should look something like this:  
 a 2
 b 0
 c 0
 d 0
 e 1
 f 0
 g 0
 h 2
 i 2
 j 0 
ect...

Comment: Actually, you need to take time to work on this because all the help on this would be useless unless you try to accomplish it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this **solution without using Arrays or List**, maybe it will help you:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int counter = 0;
        String letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"; 
        String phrase = "This is a phrase".toLowerCase();
        for (int i = 0; i < letters.length(); i++) {
            int count = 0;
            char a = letters.charAt(i);
            for (int j = 0; j < phrase.length(); j++) {
                if (a == phrase.charAt(j)) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("The letter " + letters.charAt(i) + " " + count);
        }
        
    }
```

For each letter you will have how much time it's used in you phrase.

**Result :**

```
The letter a 2
The letter b 0
The letter c 0
The letter d 0
The letter e 1
The letter f 0
The letter g 0
The letter h 2
The letter i 2
The letter j 0
The letter k 0
The letter l 0
The letter m 0
The letter n 0
The letter o 0
The letter p 1
The letter q 0
The letter r 1
The letter s 3
The letter t 1
The letter u 0
The letter v 0
The letter w 0
The letter x 0
The letter y 0
The letter z 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 0):

This is one way:

```
    String lettersString = "abcdefghijqlmnñopqrstuvwxyz";
    char[] letters = lettersString.toCharArray();
    int[] counts = new int[letters.length];
    Arrays.fill(counts, 0);
    String textBoxValue = "This is the message";
    for (int i = 0; i < textBoxValue.length(); i++) {
        char currentLetter = textBoxValue.charAt(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < letters.length; j++) {
            char letter = letters[j];
            if (currentLetter == letter ||
            currentLetter == Character.toUpperCase(letter)){
                counts[j]++;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
        //Print it your own way
        String message = letters[i] + " : " + counts[i];
        Log.d(TAG, message);
        System.out.println(message);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably this would help, just try to do a frequency Map.

```
    public static Map<Character, Integer> frequencies(String yourPrhase){
        Map<Character, Integer> frequency = new HashMap<>();
        for(final char c : str.toCharArray()){
            frequency.compute(c, (k, v) -> v == null ? 1: v++);
        }
        return frequency;
}
```

Then you can just do what you need with the frequency Map, probably print it out.

Also can try this one a little bit more functional.

```
   public static Map<String, Long> frequencies2(String yourPrhase){
    return  str.chars()
        .mapToObj(c -> String.valueOf((char) c))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(String::valueOf, Collectors.counting()));
}
```